# Why does swift make checks on bounds in for loop

Tags: swift

If i made this:

```
for i in (a...b).reverse
{

}
```

swift makes some checks on a and b, and i can get an execution error like this

```
fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound
```

Is there a way to ignore this check and let swift continue code without executing an iteration (like in C)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't form Range with end < start Check range before doing for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143197/cant-form-range-with-end-start-check-range-before-doing-for-loop)

Comment: `Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound` clearly suggest that `upperBound` means `b` needs to be greater than `lowerBound` means `a` when you form a range

Comment: What i just want is to let swift ignore this error

Comment: not possible to ignore this error .. what u want to achieve?

Comment: In most cases, half-open ranges `a..<b` are more convenient. They are empty if a==b. Or use `stride` as in the linked-to answers.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652075/elegant-swift-way-to-handle-negative-index-in-for-loop.